# What are the white lines in the Smash Run result screen?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

After the "run" part of Smash Run in Smash Bros for the 3DS, you are shown a results screen with colored bars representing the stats you've earned.  These bars sometimes have white lines in or beyond them.

What do these lines represent?
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These lines are the **average score** of all four participants. It lets you know how well in general you stack up to the opposition without having to do any math yourself.

Comment: That makes sense, but do you have a source for that?

Comment: The numbers will sit there for as long as you like before you initiate the final battle. Plenty of time to crack out a calculator and check it for yourself.